# NavigationBar setBackgroundImage issue

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar

I am setting an image to navigation bar Using following lines of code:

```
UIImage *toolBarIMG = [UIImage imageNamed: @"header.png"];  

    if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)]) { 
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:toolBarIMG  forBarMetrics:0]; 
    }
```

After using this the bar looks like same as i wanted to do it. But a problem is coming, there is a thin line of gray color is showing up at top left corner of the bar(please have a look on the image below).

[image]

can anybody please help in this?

Comment: Are you sure your image doesn't contain a 1px alpha line? Could have been created while resizing from retina to low-res image?

Comment: an obvious question - but someone had to ask:  does the image `header.png` not have a vertical line there?

Comment: header.png is fine... but i solved the problem as there is some view with white color on background, so i remove that.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do same. And all work fine. Please check your `header.png` image.

Sources for this example [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/135542/header.zip).

[image]